# How to output the number of commits with a bash script?

Tags: bash, git, shell

I am trying to output the number of Git commits between `master` and `HEAD`. The following script generates a list of commit hashes and tries to count them.

```
#!/bin/bash

git_list_commits_hashes_cmd="git rev-list --reverse master..HEAD"
commits=$($git_list_commits_hashes_cmd)
commits_count=${#commits[@]}
echo "==> ${commits_count}"
```

However, the value is always `1` regardless of the real number of commits. Why?

## Related

- [How do I find out bash shell array length?](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/finding-bash-shell-array-length-elements/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In bash scripts:

```
var=$(command)
```

sets a plain (non-array) variable based on the output of `command`.  So if the command in question produces two commit hashes H1 and H2, you have the equivalent of:

```
var="H1 H2"
```

which means that `$var` is a five character long string.  (In practice, `git rev-list` outputs 40-character SHA-1 hashes with newlines after them, so the result is one string that is 40 characters, or 81 characters, or 122 characters, and so on.)

Using:

```
var=(H1 H2)
```

will set `$var` to an array of two elements, so in this case:

```
commits=($($git_list_commit_hashes_cmd))
```

would do the trick.

Note that if you don't need the hashes themselves, `git rev-list` can produce the count directly:

```
git rev-list --count master..HEAD
```

produces just the count (there's no need for `--reverse` when not using the actual hashes).

Note also that `--reverse` reverses the normal order.  The normal order is based on committer date, wherever there's an opportunity to output more than one commit at a time (when traversing multiple legs of a merge, for instance).  You can sort based on author date, or using a topological sort.

Comment: Thank you. A great hint with the `--count` argument! Here is the [shell script](https://github.com/johnjohndoe/gradle-each) where I am using this for. Feel free to use it.

Answer (score 1):

How about just

```
git rev-list --reverse master..HEAD | wc -l
```